# Fastest way to run many startswith queries in django

Tags: sql, django

I have a list of item numbers which can be thousands of elements long. I need to search my SQL database for records that start with the numbers in my list. I am using the django ORM but raw sql works too.

As an example my list could look like this: ['123ab', '234dd', '421ad']

I am trying to find a solution that is better than looping through the list and running a startswith query every time like this:

```
for element in list:
    Item.objects.filter(
        item_number__startswith=element
    ).values(
        'item_number',
        'manufacturer'
    )
```

The problem with the loop above is that it would be very slow for a large list of item numbers. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: go for [raw sql](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/sql/) queries instead of django-orm. It's much faster than orm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A more efficient way would be to include all of the filters in a **single database query**.

For keeping your code portable and easy to understand, I'd recommend avoiding raw SQL if possible.

In the Django ORM, you can [combine your filters by using a series of `Q` objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

Refactoring your loop to use `Q` objects "OR"ed together would look like this:

```py
from django.db.models import Q

query_filters = Q()
for item_number_prefix in item_number_prefixes:
    query_filters |= Q(item_number__startswith=item_number_prefix)

queryset = Item.objects.filter(query_filters).values('item_number', 'manufacturer')
```